# Thickbox or something similar with a 100% window height

Tags: javascript, iframe, height

I am building a site with a video background and in order to keep that video playing with the visitors are browsing the site have gone with pop ups. I have used Thickbox to do this however it appears that thickbox will only allow me to use defined height where as I would like it to have a height of 100%, does anyone know if this is not the case or how I would achieve something similar with another js script?

Have tried using fancybox however which worked perfectly however it seemed to not like working with another js script, ie. the video background?

Please someone help as this is driving me mad...

This is the website, apologies in advance for the title it is just a holding page i use sometimes.

Thanks in advance.

http://pissflapspissflaps.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the javascript function found here:

[windowSize.js](http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/07/04/javascript-cross-browser-window-size-and-centering/)

and then pass `window.size()['y']` to your video background function. And then you probably have to set the value again every time the window is resized.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how does that work with thickbox. the video content resizes perfectly already

Comment: You said you can use a defined height with thickbox. Pass the result of the `size` function as height parameter to thickbox.